# Tags of the week! April 29-May 5, 2019: Research & Book — RESULTS

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, contest

## WEEK: April 29-May 5, 2019
TAGS: [research](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) and [book](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book)

At the start of this week [research](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) had 119 questions and [book](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) had 152. Let see how high we can get them by week's end.

At the end of the week, [research](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) had 139 questions and [book](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) had 160.

---

## Results

Congrats to Linksassin for a question on [research](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) and to Ricardo for a question tagged with [book](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book)

We actually had 6 questions this week with the [book](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) tag.  None of the other 5 posters chose to enter the promo.  We suggested it to some of them, but not all.  We could be more proactive about that.

It's not an actual contest though and the goal is to up our question count on our top 40 tags currently under 200.  And we did that!  Between new questions and retagging efforts, we done good.  We should be pleased with the results.

---

As a followup to our [fantastic tag contest](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1917/announcing-our-contest-results?cb=1), and to suggestions that we [continue the fun](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1925/suggestion-continue-question-pushes/1955) in a more informal way, here is Writing.SE's fifth:

## TAGS OF THE WEEK PROMO

### Rules:

- The contest runs for one week, Monday 12:01am to Sunday midnight. The day ends when StackExchange says it does.
- Post a new question using one or both of the tags of the week.
- Update the answer to this post with your name, tag(s), and a link to the question.
- You get one point for every question that, at the end of the week, is open, has one or more votes, and is correctly tagged.

### Prizes:

- One beautiful sack of bragging rights!
- Two sacks if you use both tags in the same question.

---

**Notes:**

- Can we use questions we've already posted that are within this week's boundaries?  Yes.
- The goal is to increase questions on tags that have not yet reached the magic 200 questions.  My personal focus is tags that are in the top 40 tags but under 200 questions.
- Others may take over other weeks and they may have different goals.
- Each week we'll have two tags to choose from; the tags are deliberately different from each other.

This contest is linked from [this Meta.SE post about topic challenges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327017/162102).  (Please update it for new challenges.)

For a list of all targeted tags and their progress, see https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1987/32946

Comment: Can someone sandbox this question for me (feel free to post it yourself, if you come up with a good way to put it.)  Basically I want to ask how much research should I do on a topic I feel I know very well. (it's for my grammar/writing podcast, a topic I know super-well, for 5 minute episodes.) I don't want to be too basic, but people make basic mistakes.  Should I look up, say, all apostrophe questions on ELU.SE, besides just verifying my info on my standard grammar resources?   I feel like the Q is still only half-baked, alas.

Comment: @April Yeah it feels like a question for asking a question's sake.  The answer is always "do a quick review."  I'd put something like looking up all X q's on SE into the research for examples and presentation.  Not the review.  It's possible you'd get answers that varied enough from that to make it interesting or useful, but not so much with the question as written.

Comment: I know.  I think I'm just in that cycling around mode where I want the universe to give me a rubric of What To Do and How Much Is It worth?  (I'm good at telling students what to do: myself? not as much.  )

Answer (score 4):

## Entries

Add entries to this list in the following format:

Username, tag, link to question

One entry per question, not one entry per tag.

---

- Linksassin: [research](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) [How can I effectively research for a high-fantasy setting?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/44852/33442)
- Ricardo: [book](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) [How can I generate paperback book from iBooks Author?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/44953/how-can-i-generate-paperback-book-from-ibooks-author/44955#44955)

Answer (score 1):

I think just a general "thank you" to those who post Qs on those tags, even if they don't post here, might be good -- it is boosting the question count, which is good, as you said.  Some might not want to bother with Meta.

Comment: I was very general :-)  If you'd like to make a list of the other posts, please feel free to edit either the wiki answer or the question.